# spring-security login.html and login-form on different servers

Tags: spring-security

I have a Spring MVC application with spring-security and I'd like to have the entire static content including HTML files of a web application on a different hosting solution/server. (unlike the reverse-proxy approach)

The login.html page is hosted on the public static server e.g:static.domaina.com.

The login form is hosted on the app server in e.g:api.domaina.com
Can spring security login-form store the login session for the app server although the login-form is served from the static-files server?
Can I do it without sharing session between the static and the app server?

(CORS is not an issue since I can add the required headers in the static server)